# Save Names via URL in PHP textfile?

Tags: php

I wanted to save/track names and save them in a .txt file with just calling a URL.
Let's say this is the url: `domain.com/script.php?name=daniel`

So when I call this url, `"daniel"` is written in that textfile.

`domain.com/script.php?name=alex` would safe `"alex"` in the textfile.

I assume this is an easy task, but I am not able to perform this task.

Comment: get the names from `$_REQUEST` variable and use `fwrite` to save them

Comment: lol dude!! like get a table of words and then sequel it

Comment: thanks man. Can you tell me the whole query? I would appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring all the safety you need, this is the basics. I *STRONGLY* suggest you do your homework and ensure the variable is set, ensure you can open the file, ensure the file is locked in exclusive mode, and ensure the info on the variable is valid.

```
$fp = fopen("namefile.txt","a");
fputs($fp, $_GET["name"]."\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Just a pet peeve: You should only put double quotes around strings you want parsed (i.e. `\n`).  Otherwise, you should only put single quotes so that the interpreter doesn't waste time.

Comment: To get the lock directly, you could do `file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', $_GET["name"].'\n', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`